# Easy way to reopen a command previously written with CTRL+X, CTRL+E in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Let's say I've written a complex command with the help of my favorite editor in bash. For the sake of it, let's say it's

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do
  echo $i
done
```

After running it I decide that I need to run it once again. It's no problem, as I can press UP and I'll have

```
for i in $(seq 1 10); do  echo $i; done
```

in my command history.

But now 2 questions arise:

1. Can I easily reopen this command in an editor so I can re-execute the command once again;
2. Can the editor show up the command with the original newlines included, instead of it having everything stuck up into a one-liner?

Comment: If you hit Up to select the previous command and then C-x C-e, you will get that command in your editor

Comment: You can also use the `:p` modifier to print any history expansion (`!!:p`, `!-3:p`, etc) to the command line, at which point you can then use C-x C-e.

Answer (score 1):

1. As pointed out in comments, just as before: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> when the command you want to edit is displayed.
2. There are a [shell options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) for this (irrelevant output lines of `fc -l` and the output of the command itself are skipped). With none of them set, multi-line commands are store as one command per line:

   ```
   $ for i in {1..3}; do
   > echo $i
   > done
   $ fc -l
   1258     for i in {1..3}; do
   1259     echo $i
   1260     done
   ```

   Then, there is the shell option `cmdhist` (quote from manual):

   > If set, Bash attempts to save all lines of a multiple-line command in the same history entry. This allows easy re-editing of multi-line commands.

   ```
   $ shopt -s cmdhist
   $ for i in {1..3}; do
   > echo $i
   > done
   $ fc -l
   1263     for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done
   ```

   This is the setting you seem to have had when asking the question. (You can check your settings with just `shopt`.)

   To preserve newlines, there is the `lithist` option (quote from manual):

   > If enabled, and the `cmdhist` option is enabled, multi-line commands are saved to the history with embedded newlines rather than using semicolon separators where possible.

   ```
   $ shopt -s lithist
   $ for i in {1..3}; do
   > echo $i
   > done
   $ fc -l
   1266     for i in {1..3}; do
   echo $i
   done
   ```

   This option doesn't do anything on its own, but combined with `cmdhist`, it does what you want.